# JDK NoClassDefFoundError on Mac

Tags: java, macos

When I am compiling my programs using IntelliJ and Eclipse everything works normally, but when I am running java or javac in terminal I cannot do that. I have problem:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

I set a PATH but it still doesn't work.
I tried reinstall JAVA but still does not work.

Command *which* java gives:

```
/Users/ba/anaconda3/bin/java
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I don't think your Java is installed in Anaconda3, which is a Python3 library. Try to remove `/Users/ba/anaconda3/bin` from your `$PATH`. Java is normally installed in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` in Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* settings you must pass to the Java compiler *(usually javac)* when you build your Java application. You can give these settings on the command-line and/or with environment variables set in your terminal, but you must give them, or your app won't compile. This is why you are getting the error that the compiler cannot find the *basic* definition for "java/lang/Object" -- you didn't tell it where to look.

When you use an IDE (development environment), like IntelliJ or Eclipse, they automatically do the work of providing the necessary details for you. If you're going to do that yourself on the command-line, you'll need to do it all.

**At a minimum:**  You need to have the java tools in your PATH variable in the terminal, plus you'll need to provide a "classpath" to the Java compiler so it knows where to find all of the needed libraries (directories and JAR files, etc) for your app. See this site for a little more info:

https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html

This gets to be a big topic, so either stick with an IDE or be prepared to do a little more reading.